# Why did our Meta just break? Links are white?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Mod tag text and background for most required tags have turned white/grey:

[image: Missing tag content]

And the top bar links are white, so they're barely discernible from the light grey background:

[image: Links are funny too]

This doesn't seem to be an issue on any other site metas I've looked at.

Why do you hate us??? ;)

Comment: You mean required tags, not mod tags :) mod tags are the red ones

Comment: @ArtOfCode Ah! You're totally right... clearly it's **not** the mod tags as the "Featured" tag works just fine.

Comment: Noticed it with Discussion and bug Tag

Comment: I contacted the design team and there will be a fix soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must have been [nargles](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nargle). A fix is now live.

Comment: Nargles steal things. You mean a gremlin

Comment: They stole a variable in our CSS framework.

Comment: I'm willing to bet a million dollars that you pressed the wrong button.

Comment: @Richard YOU CANNOT PROVE ANYTHING

Comment: I'll take a cheque, thanks.

Comment: Wa...wa...wait a minute. Did you really just fix [this months long bug that never got fixed](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1803/49)? I...I can't believe it. And that from some totally different bug!

Comment: @NapoleonWilson that was completely intentional and I'll take credit for the fix, but not for the other bug that we introduced — that must have been someone else.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers In this case you might also want to answer the older question. But hey, what other bug? Is there a new one?